# Not able to detect a href component in Selenium RC

Tags: selenium-rc

I have the following link 'Test'  in my application.

`<div class="tabUnselectedText" align="center">
<a href="javascript:renderPage('mainForm:consoleBeanId.3','Test' , 'testdetails.faces');">Test</a>
</div>`

When I tried Selenium IDE it gives me following code. The same code does not work with RC . Please help me out with this

selenium.click("link=Test");     // code generated with Selenium IDE and same does not work with RC. It says element is not

One more case:

`<div class="tabUnselectedText" align="center">
<a href="javascript:renderPage('mainForm:consoleBeanId.1','Notifications' , 'notifications.faces');">Notifications</a>
</div>`

15:45:04.627 INFO - Command request: click[link=Test, ] on session 2d985d284
6694d888ee13a986dc8cf67
15:45:04.658 INFO - Got result: ERROR: Element link=Test not found on sessio
n 2d985d2846694d888ee13a986dc8cf67

Comment: Please let me know fro further details

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? Does it say that it can't find the element?

Comment: yeah. It is not able to find the element. :)

Comment: It's worth getting to know the Xpath selection - it's much more powerful. 
http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_selenese_commands.html#locating-by-xpath

Comment: wat cld be the xpath in above case? I am not able to determine.

Answer (score 0):

Xpath: //div[@class='tabUnselectedText']/a

Answer (score 0):

Try with Selenium.ClickAt()